# Docker - Build image from a Dockerfile in a child folder

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile

I'm running into a problem with docker that I can't fix by looking at other references, documentation, etc. and since i'm a beginner with Docker I try my luck here. I'm working in a Next.js project that is using Docker to build the app. I'm using the example [documentation](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) of Next.js, and **that** works if I have my Dockerfile in the root of my project. However, I want to put it in a folder called `etc` and use it from there. This is giving me problems, because docker can't find the files that i'm trying to copy to the working directory, see error below.

**Structure**

```
.
├── etc
│   └── Dockerfile
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

**Command**

`docker build etc/`

**Error**

`failed to compute cache key: "/yarn.lock" not found: not found`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

I've tried a bunch of things, such as changing the files and paths. Also, in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder) they mention the `-f` flag, but that doesn't work for me either because I get the error `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.` when running `docker build -f etc/Dockerfile`. Is that outdated? Anyway, my question is how to build my app with docker when my dockerfile is not in the root of the project but in a child folder like `etc/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten the dot at the end of the command `docker build -f etc/Dockerfile .`

Comment: To add to this. The require parameter to `docker build` is the build context i.e. a path to the root of the files you want to use in your dockerfile. The `-f` option tells docker where to find your dockerfile, without it docker will just assume it's in the root of your context and called `Dockerfile`.